# How to properly test for an audio end?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, event-listener

I have an audio setup like this

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <script>
    var audio1 = new Audio("music1.mp3");
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
      console.log('hm');
      audio1.play();
    });
    audio1.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      console.log('end');
      audio1.currentTime = 0;
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I click a key to start the audio and console.log('hm'); to make sure it started but whenever the audio ends the second eventListener does not get called and I do not get the "end" message or a restart. I prefer to keep the audio in javascript and not a tag because I have already created the game and changing the audio ways changes about 45% of the game.

Am I doing things wrong? If so please tell me the proper way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Use an `<audio>` tag without the `controls` attribute and it'll be invisible as if it had `display: none` or an Audio object. The example below has the steps to create an `<audio>` tag commented.

If you have a path to a real MP3 file, then your code should work (unless references to DOM objects are actually null (ie not there)). You click a key and nothing happens? If so, you need to be focused on some tag in the page first.

**Details are commented in example**

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <!--
  Blank link is here so that the page will be automatically focused so that the user
  can start clicking keys without having to click the webpage itself first.  
  --> 
  <a href="#"></a>
  <script>
    /**
     * Make an actual <audio> tag without controls attribute and prepend it to <body>
     * Reference the <audio>
     * Assign the url to a MP3 to <audio>
     *//*
    document.body.prepend(document.createElement("audio"));
    const mp3 = document.querySelector("audio");
    mp3.src = "https://gldrv.s3.amazonaws.com/av/Florence_and_the_Machine-Dog_%20Days_are_Over.mp3";
    */
    // Uncomment the code above if you want an <audio> tag.
    // Then comment or delete the next line.
    const mp3 = new Audio("https://gldrv.s3.amazonaws.com/av/Florence_and_the_Machine-Dog_%20Days_are_Over.mp3");
   
    
    /**
     * Bind "keydown" event to document object.
     * - Space Bar key is a Play/Pause button
     * - ArrowRight key Fwd 10 sec
     * - ArrowLeft key Rev 10 sec
     * - End key end player
     */
     document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      switch (e.key) {
        case " ":
          if (mp3.paused) {
            mp3.play();
            console.log("Playing");
          } else {
            mp3.pause();
            console.log("Paused at "+mp3.currentTime+" sec");
          }
          break;
        case "ArrowLeft":
          mp3.currentTime -= 10;
          console.log("Skip Backward 10 sec at "+mp3.currentTime+" sec");
          break;
        case "ArrowRight":
          mp3.currentTime += 10;
          console.log("Skip Forward 10 sec at "+mp3.currentTime+" sec");
          break;
        case "End":
          mp3.pause();
          mp3.currentTime = 0;
          console.log("Ended");
          break;
      }
    });

    mp3.addEventListener("ended", function(e) {
      console.log('Ended');
      this.currentTime = 0;
    });
    /**
     * Programmatically focus on the dummy link so that the page is focused. User
     * must be focused on page before key events (and the majority of all events) 
     * can trigger.
     */
    document.links[0].focus();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```